# Creating dynamic index column based on date

Tags: powerbi, dax

I'm trying to add a measure to my data table that ranks the rows for each date.

The column labelled "Index" below, is what I'm trying to produce.  I've been trying with DAX using RANK/COUNT etc.; but my DAX knowledge is fairly limited.  Help is appreciated!

```
Data_Date   EWP                          Index

2021-08-02  4-250-150000-103             1
2021-08-02  4-270-100000-705             2
2021-08-03  4-220-280000-513             1
2021-08-03  4-260-171000-309             2
2021-08-03  LOE - H/375000/250/W129      3
2021-08-05  LOE - H/375000/240/Z102      1
2021-08-05  LOE - H/375000/240/Z103      2
2021-08-06  4-250-162000-406             1
2021-08-06  4-250-172000-404             2
2021-08-06  B-230-263000-504             3 
2021-08-06  B-250-263000-504             4
```

Comment: What is the purpose of the index column? What will you do with it? The order of your rows inside the data model may change all the time, when Power BI applies its algorithm for compression and storage.  Therefore, you would be better off sorting and indexing the data in the Power Query editor, before it hits the data model.

Comment: Maybe index is the wrong word, even if the first two rows were stored in different order, it is fine they are still labelled 1 and 2 respectively.  Date and EWP are static columns and won't change dynamically.

Comment: So what is the purpose of the index column? What will you do with it??

Answer (score 2):

You can use `rankx` to return the index for expected output:

```
rank = RANKX(FILTER(ALL(Sheet1),Sheet1[Data_Date]=EARLIER(Sheet1[Data_Date])),
        Sheet1[EWP],,ASC)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks Kin! This works.... is there a way to do it as a measure though? I should have mentioned I had slicers that will affect the data.  Seems EARLIER cannot be used in a measure (far as I can tell).

Comment: Not sure how to do it in measure, because `rankx` function and most of the function cannot be used to filter a visual reports, if you drag all the data to visual report, once you slice it , the rank should be filter based on the current data?